# R - When splitting an object by a datetime element, why does the date in the resulting list not have times?

Tags: r, datetime, split

I have been working on a split-apply-combine operation today where I want to split a data frame by a couple factors, one being hour of the day, using `split()`. However, when I do this, the date field in the resulting list of data frames lacks its time element. The same thing happens when I split a vector of datetimes. The following code demonstrates:

```
times <- seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct("2015-05-02"), Sys.time(), by="1 hours")
times <- split(times, format(times, "%H"))
head(times[[1]])
```

This even occurs if I create a separate variable to define my desired groupings:

```
times <- seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct("2015-05-02"), Sys.time(), by="1 hours")
hours <- format(times, "%H")
times <- split(times, hours)
head(times[[1]])
```

Though the above code is with vectors, if I do the same thing with my data frame the dates still wind up without their times.

Why does this happen? Also, is there a good way to prevent this from happening or work around it?

Comment: It's not dropped. See `head(times[[2]])` (after the first 3 lines you provided). The first element has midnight as time, and it's just not printed, but isn't dropped.

Comment: Thank you very much. That was a stupid mistake.

Comment: Actually it isn't a stupid mistake and quite confusing. It is vaguely documented in`?strptime` though: "*The default for the format methods is "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" if any element has a time component which is not midnight, and "%Y-%m-%d" otherwise*""